# changing the subdomain and SEO issue

Tags: seo, subdomain, 301-redirect

because of "government filtering" in Iran, once in a while we have to move the whole site into a new subdomain. For example i create a new sub domain on my public_html : `http://01.mydomain.com`

I know Google webmaster has a feature to change domain, but it doesn't work with sub domains.
as you can guess, the site is still accessible with www sub domain, now what's the best way to make Google to show the search results with new sub domain ? because the WWW sub domain is blocked now!
any opinion would be helpful.

Comment: Can you rewrite it with an htaccess file? Setup a 301 for everything to the new domain, then if anyone hits the old links it'll redirect them.

Comment: thanks david, i did this before (new subdomain in another folder), but it had really bad effect on SEO. now that i have both subdomains in a folder it's better. but i'm looking for a way to completely migrate from on subdomain to another.

Comment: You might be better off with a dynamic domain record which you can update on the fly to change where it's pointing. Then your domain would stay the same but where it points would change. Although you'd get downtime with the DNS propagation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with 301 redirection if i want to migrate my website to new location but as suggested by DavidYell, i wont redirect all to new domain but i will do one to one redirection.

Let me explain in details:

`domain.com` to `a.domain.com`

`domain.com/page1` to `a.domain.com/page1`

And so on...

I already implemented this for more than 10 websites of my client and all worked great.